# IBM Restful web service and FileUpload

Tags: apache, web-services, rest, file-upload

I am getting an exception while uploading a MultiPartFile to IBMRestfulServlet (IBM Rest service implementation internally uses Apache Wink.) I have seen IBM samples where InMultiPart is used as a path parameter.

Here is a code snippet from my program:

```
import org.apache.wink.common.model.multipart.InMultiPart;
import org.apache.wink.common.model.multipart.InPart;

@Path("/policyCache")
public class PolicyCacheResource {

@POST
@Path("/establishCache")
@Consumes("multipart/mixed")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String establishPolicyCache(@PathParam("file") InMultiPart multiPart) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
    String id = null;

    if(multiPart != null) {
        while(multiPart.hasNext()) {
            InPart part = multiPart.next();
            ...
        }
    }
...
```

and here is the exception. Can you please help ? Thank you.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class org.apache.wink.common.model.multipart.InMultiPart type is not a supported resource method parameter. 
at org.apache.wink.common.internal.registry.ValueConvertor.getComplexValueConverter(ValueConvertor.java:197)    
at org.apache.wink.common.internal.registry.ValueConvertor.getSingleValueConvertor(ValueConvertor.java:165) 
at org.apache.wink.common.internal.registry.ValueConvertor.createConcreteValueConvertor(ValueConvertor.java:120)
at  org.apache.wink.common.internal.registry.ValueConvertor.createValueConvertor(ValueConvertor.java:93)
```

Comment: I think @PathParam isn't needed and causing a conflict with InMultiPart

Comment: Thank you. I tried that. That exception went away. But now there is an exception coming from @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA). My web page is making a request: <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="...">
  Upload copybook<input type="file"/>
  <br/><br/>
  <input type="submit"></input>
 </form>  The exception is (415 - Unsupported Media Type). It looks like there is an issue with Wink that is bundled with Websphere. Any thoughts ?

Comment: try changing the consumes to be multipart/form-data - I agree with Aman

Answer (score 0):

please  use media type multipart/form-data in @consumes annotation.

Comment: I agree with Aman's answer.  While not sufficiently well explained.

Comment: Thanks Aman. As indicated in my comment, I have @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA) and now the control is getting into establishPolicyCache method. However, there is no file data. multiPart object is empty.

Comment: You will not get file directly but stream of the file.you need to convert back to file.You can use BufferedInMultiPart in place of InMultiPart ,it worked for me .Here is sample,hope it will be helpful.                               @Path("/uploadAudioAndImages")
 @POST
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
 public Response UploadAudioAndImages(BufferedInMultiPart bimp) throws Exception {BufferedInPart bm = (BufferedInPart) parts.get(0)InputStream useridstream = bm.getInputStream()  String userid = getStringFromInputStream(useridstream);}

Comment: Thanks Aman. This is what I have. Your code looks similar to what I have. But the parts object in this code is empty. @POST
 @Path("/establishCache")
 @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
 public String establishPolicyCache(BufferedInMultiPart mFile) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
  String id = null;
  
  List<InPart> parts = mFile.getParts();
  
  if(parts != null) {
   for(InPart part : parts) {
    if(part.getInputStream() != null) {
     String copyBookString = getFileContentsAsString(part.getInputStream());
     id = ...    }
   }
  }
  
  return quoteVersionId;
 }

Comment: Add name attribute to you html,hope it will work. <input type="file" name="filename"/>

Comment: strange. But the code worked fine when I hit the service from Chrome Rest client. Not from my html page. Definitely looks like a header issue. I compared the request coming from chrome rest client vs my client. When request is coming from chrome, I see Accept content:*/* and do not see Referer content header. <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="../rest/policyCache/establishCache">
  Upload file<input type="file"/>
  <br/><br/>
  <input type="submit"></input>
 </form>

Comment: Wow Aman. That worked. Cannot believe that it is as simple as adding the name field to the input tag. Thank you so much.